# C3.js tootltip font

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I was trying this example in `c3js.

[Demo](https://c3js.org/samples/tooltip_format.html)

Does anyone know how to increase the font size of the Tooltip contents (both title and value)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the font value for the following selectors:

```
.c3-tooltip th {
  /* for the header */
}

.c3-tooltip td.name {
  /* for the title cells */
}

.c3-tooltip td.value {
  /* for the value cells */
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 15000, 250000],
            ['data2', 100, 200, 100, 40, 150, 250]
        ],
        axes: {
            data2: 'y2'
        }
    },
    axis : {
        y : {
            tick: {
                format: d3.format("s")
            }
        },
        y2: {
            show: true,
            tick: {
                format: d3.format("$")
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        format: {
            title: function (d) { return 'Data ' + d; },
            value: function (value, ratio, id) {
                var format = id === 'data1' ? d3.format(',') : d3.format('$');
                return format(value);
            }
//            value: d3.format(',') // apply this format to both y and y2
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.c3-tooltip th {
  /* for the header */
  color: red !important;
}

.c3-tooltip td.name {
  /* for the title cells */
  color: green;
}

.c3-tooltip td.value {
  /* for the value cells */
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.12/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.12/c3.min.js"></script>
<div id='chart'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom `font-size` to the `tspan` element:

```
tspan {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```